# Add a value from a list to the end of a value in another list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I am sure that this is a basic task and that the answer is somewhere on google but the problem I have is that I don't know what this is "called" so I am having a bad time trying to google it, almost every page demonstrates merging two lists which is not in my interest.

I basically have two lists where I would like to add the values from the list "add" to the the end of each word in the list "stuff" and print it out.

```
 add = ['123', '12345']
 stuff = ['Cars', 'Suits', 'Drinks']
```

**Desired output**

> ```
>     Cars123
>     Cars12345
>     Suits123
>     Suits12345
>     Drinks123
>     Drinks12345
> ```

Thanks in advance, and sorry again for bad research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't just use a nested loop? It's certainly the simplest solution.

```
for i in stuff:
    for j in add:
        print(i+j)
```

gives

```
Cars123
Cars12345
Suits123
Suits12345
Drinks123
Drinks12345
```

This assumes that both lists are strings.

As a side point, shadowing function names like add is generally a bad idea for variables, so I would consider changing that.

Comment: Thanks for the nested loop and the feedback, this works. Is there any downside with nested loops?

Comment: @Gustaf No, you may even see some performance benefits for this approach over the itertools methods suggested in other answers.

Comment: @nathan.medz: You're right, I added timing info to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore what I said about combinations in the comment!

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> add = ['123', '12345']
>>> stuff = ['Cars', 'Suits', 'Drinks']
>>> for a, s in product(add, stuff):
...     a+s
...     
'123Cars'
'123Suits'
'123Drinks'
'12345Cars'
'12345Suits'
'12345Drinks'
```

Addendum: Timing information: This code, which compares the nested loop with the `product` function from `itertools` does indeed show that the latter takes more time, in the ratio of about `2.64`.

```
import timeit

def approach_1():
    add = ['123', '12345']; stuff = ['Cars', 'Suits', 'Drinks']
    for a in add:
        for s in stuff:
            a+s

def approach_2():
    from itertools import product
    add = ['123', '12345']; stuff = ['Cars', 'Suits', 'Drinks']
    for a, s in product(add, stuff):
        a+s

t1 = timeit.timeit('approach_1()','from __main__ import approach_1', number=10000)
t2 = timeit.timeit('approach_2()','from __main__ import approach_2', number=10000)

print (t2/t1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did some googling on Itertools, looks like a good library. Nested loops seem to be a bit easier though, perhaps some downside with nesting though(?).

Comment: @Gustaf: To be honest, I don't know, I would have to time the two bits of code.

Comment: @Gustaf: I've added timing, in the addendum.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for i in stuff:
    for j in add:
        print(i+j)
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Anirudh, it outputs "Cars123" and "Suits12345"

Comment: Yeah my bad. I edited the answer. Btw if you still haven't found what its called, its - traversing multiple lists simultaneously. Use zip from itertools - it seems easy

Answer (score 0):

You need two `for` loops for that:

```
for stuff_element in stuff:
    for add_element in add:
         print(stuff_element+add_elements)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcos, nested loop seems to be the thing I should have searched for.

Comment: Good, hope it helps.